# Contract not disbursing MetaCoin to parent account

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle

I've combined `MetaCoin` and created an `Ownable` contract to allow for my Relay contract have access to `MetaCoin` methods and variables. Everything is successfully deployed using truffle. My assumption is that `Relay` (thereby the default account in web3.eth.accounts) should have access to methods and variables from `MetaCoin`. Below is the contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;
import "./ConvertLib.sol";

// This is just a simple example of a coin-like contract.
// It is not standards compatible and cannot be expected to talk to other
// coin/token contracts. If you want to create a standards-compliant
// token, see: https://github.com/ConsenSys/Tokens. Cheers!

contract Ownable {
  address public owner;

  function Ownable() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

   modifier onlyOwner() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) {
      throw;
    }
    _;
  }

  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
    if (newOwner != address(0)) {
      owner = newOwner;
    }
  }

}

contract MetaCoin is Ownable{
    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    function MetaCoin() {
        balances[tx.origin] = 10000;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool sufficient) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function getBalanceInEth(address addr) returns(uint){
        return ConvertLib.convert(getBalance(addr),2);
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }
}

contract Relay is MetaCoin {
address public owner;
uint public count;
address[] oracles;
uint public fee;


  function Relay() {
    owner = msg.sender;
    count = 0;
    fee = 10;
  }


  function fundRelay() payable returns (bool) {
    if (owner != msg.sender) throw;

  }

function approveExternalTransaction() {
  count++;
  if (count == 3) {
    releaseFunds();
  }
}
  function releaseFunds () {

      sendCoin(owner, fee);

  }
}
```

I am acting as a manual oracle and I call `approveExternalTransaction()` 3 times, on the third time `sendCoin()` should be called. It currently is not being called. `sendCoin()` is not called when I manually call the method either.

I'm running this all successfully using truffle and I expect the pre-funded contract to release the funds to the owner (account 0 in web3.eth.accounts), but nothing is happening.

One hint is that when I call `Relay.at(relay).balance()` I get the error `Relay.at(...).balance is not a function`. Does being `Ownable` not inherit the `balance` variable declarations as well? Or is this an issue with either truffle or the way I've constructed my contracts?

Thank you for any help.

---

UPDATE -- Found this guide https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/interactions-between-contracts/

Changed these functions -

```
function approveExternalTransaction(address coinContractAddress) {
    count++;
    if (count == 3) {
      releaseFunds(coinContractAddress);
    }
  }

  function sendCoin(address coinContractAddress, address receiver, uint amount) {
        MetaCoin m = MetaCoin(coinContractAddress);
      if(m.getBalance(msg.sender) >= amount) {
        balances[msg.sender] += amount;
        balances[owner] -= amount;
      m.sendCoin(owner, fee);
    }
  }

function releaseFunds (address coinContractAddress) {
    sendCoin(coinContractAddress, owner, fee);
 }

}
```

The issue now is when I set `address = MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) { return instance.address; })` and then call `Relay.at(relay).approveExternalTransaction(address)` I am getting the following error:

```
BigNumber Error: new BigNumber() not a number: [object Object]
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Did you mean `Relay.at(relay).balances()` with an 's'? Being ownable *doesn't* prevent inheritance of the getter function for the public mapping called balances.

Comment: Says `TypeError: Relay.at(...).balances is not a function`. When I call `Relay.at(relay).sendCoin(relay, 10)` I get a successful transaction but no coins get moved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. It was a couple issues. First with my `Relay` contract, I changed the names of the `address` variables that the functions were receiving. Because they were originally all `coinContractAddress` it was not playing nice with truffle. Here is what I changed them to:

```
  function approveExternalTransaction(address externalAddress) {
    count++;
    if (count == 3) {
      releaseFunds(externalAddress);
    }
  }

  function sendCoin(address sendAddress, address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool sufficient) {
            MetaCoin m = MetaCoin(sendAddress);
          m.sendCoin(owner, fee);
      }

function releaseFunds (address releaseAddress) {
    sendCoin(releaseAddress, owner, fee);
  }
```

As a result, I had no issues. The second issue was me not properly setting the `MetaCoin` address in truffle. I was calling:

```
address = MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) { return instance.address; })
```

instead of setting the address `=` inside the callback

```
address = MetaCoin.deployed().then(function(instance) { address = instance.address; })
```

Everything worked perfectly after that.

Comment: Cool.  But that last part looks weird. Surely just `let address; MetaCoin.deployed().then(.... { address = instance.address})`

Answer (score 0):

I've deployed your contract with remix and made 3 calls of approveExternalTransaction(). SendCoin() is successfully called, but let's see the result (event, that generated by `SendCoin()` function):

[image]

You've tried to transfer ether from owner to owner. It is seen from contract too: `owner = msg.sender` at deploying. Maybe this change will do, what you expect from function:
`sendCoin(owner, fee);` -> `sendCoin(msg.sender, fee);`?

**UPDATE**

See full code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Ownable {
  address public owner;

  function Ownable() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

   modifier onlyOwner() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) {
      throw;
    }
    _;
  }

  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
    if (newOwner != address(0)) {
      owner = newOwner;
    }
  }

}

contract MetaCoin is Ownable{
    mapping (address => uint) balances;

    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint256 _value);

    function MetaCoin() {
        balances[msg.sender] = 10000;
    }

    function sendCoin(address receiver, uint amount) returns(bool sufficient) {
        if (balances[msg.sender] < amount) return false;
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        balances[receiver] += amount;
        Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount);
        return true;
    }

    function getBalance(address addr) constant returns(uint) {
        return balances[addr];
    }
}

contract Relay is MetaCoin {
address public owner;
uint public count;
address[] oracles;
uint public fee;


  function Relay() {
    owner = msg.sender;
    count = 0;
    fee = 10;
  }


  function fundRelay() payable returns (bool) {
    if (owner != msg.sender) throw;

  }

function approveExternalTransaction(address receiver) {
    count++;
    if (count == 3) {
      releaseFunds(receiver);
    }
  }

function releaseFunds (address receiver) {
    sendCoin(receiver, fee);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to step out for a minute but I will check when I get home.

Comment: Viktor, this did not work. I also changed the parent account to acct2 - `relay = Relay.new({from: acct2}).then(function(instance) { relay = instance.address;})` to avoid that and still not working.

Comment: @MichaelO'Rourke I've update my answer with full code: try it in Remix - it works.

Comment: Why would it work in remix and not in the truffle console?